# Deleting the rows in COLUMNS that do not match the rows in another column (all belonging to a 1 dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

My dataframe looks like this:

```
A         B    C    D        E   F   G  H       I      J 
FP002    12     FP001   113 406 519  85 82  FP001   6240
FP003    7610   FP002   99  552 651  49 64  FP002   12294
FP005    12,    FP003   102 131 1416 24  89 FP003   761
FP005    1250   FP004   94  739 833 122 215 FP004   400
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
A         B    C         D   E       F       G       H       I       J
FP002    12     FP002   99  552     651      49      64   FP002   12294
FP003    7610   FP003   102 1314    1416    247      89   FP003  761
FP005    12,    
FP005    1250
```

So basically retaining the rows following what is in Column A.

My code to start is this:

```
dfR = df1.join( df1 ,on=['A','C'], how='inner')
```

but it's not giving me the result i need.

Comment: Is it preliminary known that all compared values are contained in `A`, `C` and `I` columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the chunks using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `axis=1`, the `join` with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) after deduplicating with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
from functools import reduce

# start groups based on first row whenever a value starts with "FP"
group = df.iloc[0].astype(str).str.startswith('FP').cumsum()
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]

out = reduce(lambda a,b: a.join(b, how='left'), 
             (d.set_index([d.iloc[:, 0].to_numpy(),
                           d.groupby(d.iloc[:, 0]).cumcount().to_numpy()])
              for k, d in df.groupby(group, axis=1))
            )
```

Output:

```
             A     B      C      D      E       F     G     H      I        J
FP002 0  FP002    12  FP002   99.0  552.0   651.0  49.0  64.0  FP002  12294.0
FP003 0  FP003  7610  FP003  102.0  131.0  1416.0  24.0  89.0  FP003    761.0
FP005 0  FP005   12,    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN
      1  FP005  1250    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN
```

Note that `groupby` on `axis=1` will be deprecated in the future, the correct approach will then be:

```
from functools import reduce

group = df.iloc[0].astype(str).str.startswith('FP').cumsum()

out = reduce(lambda a,b: a.join(b, how='left'), 
             ((d2:=d.T).set_index([d.iloc[0].to_numpy(),
                                   d2.groupby(d.iloc[0]).cumcount().to_numpy()])
              for k, d in df.T.groupby(group))
            )
```

Intermediate that is passed to `reduce` to perform the left join:

```
[             A     B
 FP002 0  FP002    12
 FP003 0  FP003  7610
 FP005 0  FP005   12,
       1  FP005  1250,
              C    D    E     F    G    H
 FP001 0  FP001  113  406   519   85   82
 FP002 0  FP002   99  552   651   49   64
 FP003 0  FP003  102  131  1416   24   89
 FP004 0  FP004   94  739   833  122  215,
              I      J
 FP001 0  FP001   6240
 FP002 0  FP002  12294
 FP003 0  FP003    761
 FP004 0  FP004    400]
```

NB. you can also use other logics to form the groups, for instance to start groups whenever the data is not numeric:

```
group = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[0], errors='coerce').isna().cumsum()
```

Or even fully manually:

```
group = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Or with an explicit list of indices:

```
group = df.columns.isin(['A', 'C', 'I']).cumsum()
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. I got an error: 
NameError: name 'group' is not defined

Comment: @kiwi_kimchi Oops sorry, forgot to copy it, see update

Comment: Btw, I used the fact that strings start with "FP" to form groups but you could also pass a custom list of groups, like `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]` if you want.

Comment: I added more options to group the data, but best would be to clarify exactly how you would identify the columns that have the FP identifiers

Comment: I get an error:     ((d2:=d.T).set_index([d.iloc[0].to_numpy(),
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax...what is d2?

Comment: `:=` is the walrus operator, only available in python ≥3.8. For older python, use a custom function in which you manually perform the assignment.